# Arbitrary shape getting drawn in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a graph using HTML5 canvas element. The graph consists of vertices and edges connecting these vertices. I'm representing the vertices by small circles and edges by lines connecting the circles.

In my project, I want to change the position of vertices, when a 'Next' button is pressed. Shown below is a state of the canvas when the page is first loaded:

[image]

When the 'Next' button is clicked the graph is redrawn, based on the new coordinates of the vertices. However, there seems to be a error with the rendering as shown below:

[image]

Strangely, I am not using the fill() functions anywhere, so I am not able to understand why the filled portion is coming. Following is the code for draw() function that is used for drawing the graph:

```
function draw(position)
{
    var canvas_elem = document.getElementById('drawing');

    // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
    if(canvas_elem.getContext)
    {
        // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
        var canvas = canvas_elem.getContext('2d');

        // Clear canvas
        canvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_elem.width, canvas_elem.height);

        var data = data_array[num_vertices+1+position].split(",");

        // Draw all vertices
        for( var i=0; i<num_vertices; i++)
        {
            canvas.arc(data[2*i], data[2*i+1], radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            canvas.fillStyle = 'black';
            canvas.fill();
        }

        // Connect vertices by lines according to adjacency matrix
        for(var i=0;i<num_vertices; i++)
        {
            for(var j=i; j<num_vertices; j++)
            {
                if(adjacency[i][j]==1)
                {
                    canvas.beginPath();
                    canvas.moveTo(data[2*i],data[2*i+1]);
                    canvas.lineTo(data[2*j],data[2*j+1]);
                    canvas.stroke();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please use an HTML5 compatible browser.");
    }
}
```

Any leads on what might be happening here?

---

Take following values of these variables for debugging:

```
data_array=[
"10",
"0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
"1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1",
"1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1",
"0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1",
"0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1",
"0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0",
"0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0",
"0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0",
"0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0",
"0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0",
"10,2,35.4,23.3,88.9,100,210,350,70,500,412,208,336,112,45,32,89,92,102,23",
"30,4,19.4,35.3,80.9,90,230,310,120,440,400,220,330,105,40,29,80,89,90,18"
]

num_vertices=10
```

Comment: Can you give us the info inside `data_array` and `num_vertices`? Check this fiddle for the missing pieces; http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/AZLqp/

Comment: Hi....please find the info you asked in the edit I've made to my post. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

The `.arc()` method adds points to the current path, and the `.fill()` method fills in the current path.  If you keep calling `.arc()`, you are re-using the same path, so it eventually gets filled. Start a new path with `.beginPath()`:

```
// Draw all vertices
for( var i=0; i<num_vertices; i++)
{
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.arc(data[2*i], data[2*i+1], radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    canvas.fill();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PAPr5/2/

Or, start a new sub-path using `.moveTo()`. This let's you paint all the points at once with a single call to `.fill()`.

```
// Draw all vertices
for (var i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++) {
    var x = data[2 * i];
    var y = data[2 * i + 1]
    canvas.moveTo(x, y);
    canvas.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
}
canvas.fill();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PAPr5/5/

[According to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-arc), `.arc()` should not create a new path or sub-path.  The implementation of `.arc()` in Google Chrome does not conform to the specification.  In Chrome, each call to `.arc()` results in a new sub-path being created.  This behavior is non-standard.

Comment: Sorry, that did not help. And as far as I know, if fill() method is used, then you don't need to explicitly close the path. It is done automatically. Read here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial%2FDrawing_shapes

Comment: @aakashbhowmick - `.fill()` does an *implicit* closePath, but doesn't actually modify the path by either marking it as closed or by adding points. Even an explicit call to `closePath()` isn't good enough because it only closes the current *sub-path*.  The next call to `arc()` would add a line to your path from the last arc to the new arc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a silly mistake. I forgot to call closePath() after drawing each line.

Comment: Are you only testing in Chrome?  Because, in my testing in IE and FireFox, if you don't call `beginPath()` for the arcs, the entire path is filled in black.  http://jsfiddle.net/PAPr5/2/